# What're the differences between commands with/without the `default:` prefix?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

List of commands with the `default:` prefix:

- `default:compositionEnd`
- `default:compositionStart`
- `default:compositionType`
- `default:cut`
- `default:paste`
- `default:redo`
- `default:replacePreviousChar`
- `default:type`
- `default:undo`

And they all have a version that doesn't have the `default:` prefix, what are the differences between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from [vim-sample/README.md](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/vim-sample/README.md):

> - When a `keydown` is not matched by any keybinding rule, it might produce a character. This is dispatched to the `type` command.
> - It is, therefore, possible for an extension to **overwrite** the `type` command and handle characters instead of the VS Code editor.
> - There is a `default:type` command that maps to the VS Code editor's type handler in case an extension wishes to delegate back typing to VS Code.

For an example of usage, see [vim-sample/src/extension.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/vim-sample/src/extension.ts).